# Making small polar plots inside a scatterplot- Python

Tags: python, data-visualization, data-science

I have edited to make my question more specific.I have a Dataset with 4 variables: 'x','y','Length', and 'Direction'. Variable 'Direction' is Polar. I am asked to make a scatterplot and then change each point into a small polar plot reflecting its length and direction. I tried making vectors using quiver but the result was found unsatisfactory. I am attaching my code for a scatterplot, a Sample DataFrame, and a png which shows my desired output.[image: scatterplot with each point changed into a small polar plot]

```
bc = pd.DataFrame({'x':[2,4,6], 'y':[1,3,5], 'Length':[10,25,23], 'Direction':[-86,-85,-80]})   
plt.figure(figsize=(14, 7))
ax = sns.scatterplot(x="x", y="y", data=bc)
plt.title('Scatter Plot of x and y')
```

Comment: Did you already look into [`quiver`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.quiver.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.quiver)?

Comment: @JohanC. I did. I have edited the question so readers know what exactly i want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a possible approach. A triangle is created with the given x and y, using taking the angle and the length into account. If the default orientation (zero angle pointing to the right) isn't the desired one, minus signs can be added to the sines and/or the cosines. Also, the role of sines and cosines can be interchanged to mirror the angle diagonally.

To prevent that angles look deformed, `set_aspect('equal')` can be used.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

bc = pd.DataFrame({'x': [2, 4, 6], 'y': [1, 3, 5], 'Length': [10, 25, 23], 'Direction': [-86, -85, -80]})
plt.figure(figsize=(14, 7))

delta = 15  # half of the aperture angle (in degrees)
length_factor = 1 / bc['Length'].max()  # this makes the longest 1 unit long
for x, y, length, dir in zip(bc['x'], bc['y'], bc['Length'], bc['Direction']):
    for is_backgr in (True, False):
        if is_backgr:
            arc_angles = np.linspace(dir + delta, dir + 360 - delta, 32)
        else:
            arc_angles = np.linspace(dir - delta, dir + delta, 10)
        c_arr = np.cos(np.radians(arc_angles))
        s_arr = np.sin(np.radians(arc_angles))
        r = length * length_factor
        x_arr = x + np.pad(c_arr * r, (1, 1))
        y_arr = y + np.pad(s_arr * r, (1, 1))
        plt.fill(x_arr, y_arr, c='grey' if is_backgr else 'crimson', alpha=0.2)
        plt.plot(x_arr, y_arr, c='black' if is_backgr else 'crimson', lw=0.5 if is_backgr else 2)
ax = sns.scatterplot(x="x", y="y", data=bc, s=100)
ax.set_title('Scatter Plot of x and y')
ax.set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: Is there any way to make a circle around each point to make it look like a polar plot?

Comment: Is the updated answer what you're asking? If not, where exactly do you need the circles?

Comment: I am asked to make a Polar Plot centered around each point. What you have done is amazing, we can just make a black circle with a radius exactly that of cones you have made. Red part will determine length and direction like above.